# How to Authorized a custom created method in Rails by Pundit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pundit

I have created custom method in rails 4

```
def duplicate    
    new_house = @house.amoeba_dup  
    respond_to do |format|
        if new_house.save        
           format.html { render action: 'new', notice: 'Category Attribute Added Successfully' }
        else
           format.html { render action: 'new' }        
        end
    end    
end
```

But it give `Pundit::AuthorizationNotPerformedError` when I call duplicate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) is detecting that your new controller method is not checking for authorization. This typically is triggered by a line like this in your controller:

`after_action :verify_authorized`

So change your new method to this:

```
def duplicate    
  new_house = @house.amoeba_dup
  authorize new_house
  respond_to do |format|
    if new_house.save        
      format.html { render action: 'new', notice: 'Category Attribute Added Successfully' }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }        
    end
  end    
end
```

You also need to update your `house_policy.rb` to add a `duplicate?` method. The example below assumes the permission is the same as for the create method:

```
# policies/house_policy.rb
class HousePolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def duplicate?
    create?
  end
```